# Can someone provide an example of how to mock directory list in Elixir?

Tags: unit-testing, elixir

In Python you can do something like this, usually for unit testing:

```
>>> import os
>>> from mock import MagicMock
>>> os.listdir = MagicMock(return_value=['file1.txt', 'file2.txt', 'file3.txt'])
>>> os.listdir('./test')
['file1.txt', 'file2.txt', 'file3.txt']
```

How do you achieve the same thing in Elixir ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no Elixir specific mocking framework.  There's [Meck](https://github.com/eproxus/meck) for mocking Erlang and that's callable from Elixir.  I'm not quite clear on the use case here.  If you need a make-believe list of files that you get from [File.ls](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/v1.0/elixir/File.html#ls/1) then I would just wrap the call to *File.ls* inside of another function and build a mock version of that function.  The code would look like this:

```
defmodule MyFiles do
  def get_file_list(dir, mock) do
    if mock, do:["file1.txt", "file2.txt", "file3.txt"], else: (File.ls(dir))
  end
end
```

And you'd call it like this:

```
MyFiles.get_file_list(".", false)
#Actual list of files

MyFiles.get_file_list(".", true)
["file1.txt","file2.txt", "file3.txt"]
```

Mocking etc. was all [recently discussed](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/elixir-lang-talk/oYXyvEUi64Y/qRE9FzXBCQAJ) on the Elixir Lang Talk mailing list.

---

EDIT: Per Patrick Oscity there is an [Elixir wrapper for Meck](https://www.github.com/jjh42/mock).